# django change form field in .html template output

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I create a form based on a model , like seen below:

```
class ContactSelectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    contacts = ManyToManyByLetter(Contact, field_name="first_name")

    class Meta:
        model = ContactSelection
        exclude = ('created_by',)
```

When I process this view I see at the .html output a field labeled with "Contact".
Now I`m wondering whether it is possible to change this output. For example I want to name this field not "Contact" but "Selected Contacts".

This is the form processing part of the .html template:

```
<form action="{{ request.path }}" method="POST">
        <div> 
            <fieldset class="module aligned"> 
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <div class="form-row">
                    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                        {{ hidden }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
```

If somebody is wondering what ManyToManyByLetter(Contact, field_name="first_name") in the form is, check out http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/ . A very helpful many2many javascript library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try setting the fields label?
[(the docs)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label)

```
contacts = ManyToManyByLetter(Contact, field_name="first_name", label="Selected Contacts")
```

Comment: No I didn`t tried it before. But it works. Thank you. I should become more familiar with the docs and not trying to search everything on google.

Comment: You're welcome. Yea. the docs are great. and anyway, its almost always the first result for searches like django+form+label